# Is passing paramters to a web to lead form and send them back to SF a good idea?

Tags: account, contact

Here's the user story:

> What I want to do is send out an email to an Account/ Contact and ask them if their information in an email template is correct. If it is, let us know, and if not update what's wrong.

Implementation idea:

> I want to give them a link to a webform where they can update their information. It can be blank, and they update only the things that are needed, or give them a box to confirm their info is right. When they submit the form, I want to include the ID that's in the paramater to hit salesforce.  I assme I do this by javascript `window.location.href` and set it to a hidden variable on the web to  lead.

When the Web to lead form hits SF, I'd do a SOQL on the Account/Contact and make the updates, and then delete the lead. This seems Hackish...

Is there a better and cheap way to do this? Communities would be too expensive for this.

Comment: May be a silly question, but what's the advantage of using Web-to-lead here? If you're going to be having them filling out a form anyway, why not just apply your changes with the API directly to the Account/Contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use case has been implemented by SFDC as default functionality. look at "stay-in-touch"requests.  I have this setup in my org for 210 users.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_update.htm&language=en_US

Comment: i think that might work, but i didn't think you can customize the form? that might axe things.  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrpvAAC

Comment: You can't customize the form itself; however, you can customize the body of the email by going into Setup>Email>My Stay-in-Touch Settings.  There is an idea under product team review on the exchange for SFDC to implement the ability to customize the form in which your contact receives.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrpvAAC